# Wrong string format when i use persian and english together in Node Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, farsi

I have a node js project with MySql database. I have to use Persian data in my DB like:

`UserModel = {id: 1200,  firstName: 'صابر',  lastName: 'سجادی' ,  nationalCode:'4640147800', displayName: 'saber-sajadi',  status: 1, createDateTime: null  };`  
so for run stored procedure i need to convert object to string with this Code:

```
let objectToString = (object) => {
    let _string = "";
    let i = 1;
    for (let key in object) {
        var val = object[key];
        _string += (val == undefined || val == null) ? `null` : `'` + val + `' `;
        if (i < Object.keys(object).length) {
            _string += " , ";
            i++;
        }
    }
    return _string;
}
```

I expect the output of the function to be as follows:
[image] 
but it return:
`1200,'صابر','سجادی','4640147800','saber-sajadi','1',''`

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: your output is OK. it's a RTL problem for your text editor. you can copy and paste your output to nodepad++ or word to see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use this function to solve problem:
`function wrap(str){ return '\u202B' + str + '\u202C'; }`